Compilation time >15s for a one-line document on VSCode and TexLive
I always used overleaf but I now need to work offline, so I installed the VSCode extension Latex Workhop and TexLive on my Windows 11 machine. Everything works nice except for the compiling time: compiling a file with just half a line of text takes around 15 seconds. Compiling it again changing a single letter does not change the compiling time. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the log file generated.

Does the Drive in your path mean the folder is on a some kind of cloud storage?

No, it's a local folder that is mirrored in the cloud

Can you try in a folder which is not mirrored to a cloud?

Just did, for some reason in a non-mirrored folder the compilation time is reduced to 5 seconds circa, which is still a lot.

You seem to load a some packages with special fonts etc. Loading those can take a moment.

On overleaf it take less than a second, I don't think that the packages can be the issue

Overleaf might have better hardware. 5 seconds on a consumer computer does not sound so extraordinary.

Mine is a surface pro 9, released less than a year ago, I find it hard to believe that overleaf can provide more computational power since it's notoriously slower than local compilers for long documents. 5 seconds are not a lot for a decent size document but comparing to what I read online it is outrageous for a one-line document

You do realise that OverLeaf runs the doc several times automatically? Your local editor might not do that.

If you share your complete document here, we could test how long it takes on other PCs for comparison.

Also it is a good idea to always test such things out side of the editor, just to rule out strange editor issues. But it is known that on Windows on anything that constantly syncs to the cloud compilation is slower as the sync is trying to sync to the cloud while the compilation is runing so there might be some issues with some file locking. At least we've seen this with some of our windows users using OneDrive.

"No, it's a local folder that is mirrored in the cloud" that can have a significant implication on time, try a non mirrored folder first (as has been mentioned already)

Just in case, suppress rerunfilecheck.
